# libinput randomly misses mouse scroll events

Tags: mouse, logitech, scrolling, libinput, mouse-wheel

Randomly maybe 1 out of 50, a few ticks of the mouse scroll is not working. The next ones work fine.

I'm using Ubuntu with Wayland.

```
▶ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

The mouse is a Logitech MX Anywhere 3. I am using Solaar, and `imhweel` (to fix another scroll probably-unrelated bug regarding Chromium-based apps).

I've done a few investigations.

- `libinput` doesn't catch these events (They do not appear when running `libinput debug-events`).
- `dmesg` shows nothing.
- `journalctl` shows nothing.
- The issue is the same whether I use the mouse with the USB dongle or via blutooth.
- The issue is not there when using another mouse (cheap wired Asus mouse).
- The issue is not there on Windows, which proves that the issue is software.

What further step can I try to address my issue?

Thanks!